How to Implement Job Scheduling with Exponential Backoff and Real-Time Status Updates in Node.js?
I'm working on a job scheduling system in Node.js where I need to:
Schedule jobs to run at specified times.
Retry failed jobs with an exponential backoff (i.e., progressively longer delays between retries).
Provide real-time job status updates to connected clients.
For the job scheduling, I'm using Bull (a Redis-based job queue) and have tried setting up retry logic. However, I'm struggling to implement exponential backoff correctly, especially while keeping the client updated with each retry attempt in real time.
Here’s the code I’ve tried so far:
const Queue = require('bull');
const jobQueue = new Queue('jobQueue');

// Job processor function
jobQueue.process(async (job) => {
    try {
        // Simulating a job that may fail
        const result = await someAsyncFunction();
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Job failed');
    }
});

// Add a job with retry options
jobQueue.add({ /* job data */ }, {
    attempts: 5,
    backoff: {
        type: 'exponential',
        delay: 1000, // Start with a 1-second delay
    }
});

// Real-time status updates to the client (using Socket.io)
jobQueue.on('completed', (job, result) => {
    io.emit('job-status', { id: job.id, status: 'completed', result });
});

jobQueue.on('failed', (job, error) => {
    io.emit('job-status', { id: job.id, status: 'failed', error: error.message });
});

The code schedules retries but doesn't properly implement exponential backoff. The retry interval doesn't increase as expected. Plus, I'm unsure how to provide real-time status updates for each retry attempt. My goal is to have the delay double each time a job fails, and for the client to receive a status update on every retry attempt.
I tried setting backoff: { type: 'exponential', delay: 1000 }, hoping it would handle the exponential backoff automatically. However, the delays between retries don’t seem to increase as expected. I also attempted to use job.attemptsMade to calculate custom delays, but it didn’t integrate well with Bull. Additionally, handling real-time updates for each retry is challenging, as I’m unsure how to emit an event at each retry attempt.
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated!
